# Perl (or C printf) back one tab, possible?

Tags: c, perl, tabs, printf

We all know how to print a string one tab further with \t

```
printf ("Hello\tthere!\n");
```

which outputs:

```
Hello    there!
```

What about printing one tab backwards? I know we can just use \r to start back from the beginning of the line, but there are situation when indentation is more complex than that, I am looking for something like \bt (if it existed) such that I could write:

```
printf ("Hello\tthere! \n\tHow\n\btare you?\n");
```

to get in output:

```
Hello    there!
             How
         are you?
```

**Edit**

I am surprised by the amount and speed of replies here, and sometimes even by the uselessness of some comments, but only a few. What I am trying to achieve is of course more complex than this, it's properly formatting an XML file to be easily readable. I wanted to be sure there wasn't an easier way, the response confirmed there wasn't thanks.

**Edit 2**

Sorry guys, you are right to vote down this question, first because I didn't specify I was writing to a text file, secondly because I was assuming tabs could be "remembered" by the file handler. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: certainly reads like an XY problem.  What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: If you're going to try and demonstrate a formatting question you should probably make sure your sample output is correct. I assume it is not intentional that `How` seems to be indented a few extra spaces? You should probably explain what you think `\bt` does.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `printf`.

Comment: Nothing close to your `\bt` exists, you will have to emulate this behaviour by printing the adequate number of tabs/space on the new line.

Comment: @melpomene: Why this should have nothing to do with printf?

Comment: Because the escape sequence `\t` is part of the language (string literal syntax), not the library function `printf`. And for your problem it doesn't matter whether you use `printf` or other functions for outputting text (Perl: `print`, `syswrite`; C: `fputc`, `fputs`, `fwrite`).

Comment: that fine @melpomene, even if I wasn't trying to make a dissertation on C or Perl but just to picture the scenario, anyway you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *printf* you control how much tabbing is taking place explicitly.  To back tab you would just use fewer tabs.  From the example you provided it looks like you are expecting the tab level to be remembering, and have **How** indented farther than it really will be when printed.  It would appear at the same tab stop as **there!** and **are you?**

Assuming with:

```
printf ("Hello\tthere! \n\tHow\n\btare you?\n");
```

You are expecting to see:

```
Hello   there! 
    How
are you?
```

Then just don't add the tab before **are you?** and you will get what you want.  To get fewer tabs, just add fewer **\t** symbols to your *printf*.  *printf* doesn't have any *memory* of what tabbing has occurred before.

```
printf ("Hello\tthere! \n\tHow\nare you?\n");
```

Comment: You are right Stephen, I should have added the info that I am writing in a text file, which "remembers".

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi No, text files don't "remember".

Comment: You are perhaps writing to serial port or some similar special file, which does not translate `\n` to `\r\n`?

Comment: @anishsane Seems unlikely given that this is supposed to go to an XML file.

Comment: @melpomene: you are damn right, I got confused. OMG I have to keep track of the number of tabs then. Thank you for remembering me some of the basics.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no special character to do what you want. Even the behavior of `\b` is dependent on the platform.

`\bt` is simple the backspace character followed by the letter `t`. So that syntax is supported but there's no special behavior.

But why do you need that here? Why not just use:

```
printf("Hello\tthere!\r\n\tHow\r\nare you?\n");
```

Comment: `\r\n` is redundant. Just use `\n`.

Comment: Right, which is why the question doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. `prinf()` should treat a newline as a carriage return, newline pair. So why the need to backspace on a new line?

Comment: *The I/O system* should treat newline as a carriage return, *linefeed* pair *on platforms where that is the convention*.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to "back tab", but there are other options:

As you noted, `\t` gives you a tab forward.

`\b` can give you a backspace, so you can "back up" with that.

There are also some less-frequently-used ones:
`\f` is a form feed/new page (eject page from printer)
`\v` is a vertical tab (move down one line, on the same column)

So using the other options you can simulate what you want.

```
printf("Hello, this is\n\t\tjust a test.\n");
printf("Hello, this is\v\b\bjust a test.\n");
```

Ends up looking like:

```
Hello, this is
        just a test.
Hello, this is
    just a test.
```

You could then simplify your code with something like:

```
#define BACKTAB "\v\b\b"

printf("Hello, this is%sjust a test.\n", BACKTAB);
```

I think that's the best you can do

Comment: Yes @Mike, if I only had to do that, your suggestion would work. Thanks.